# Simulate a post to bypass redirection

Tags: php, curl

I need to access a page html using curl. The problem is that this page always redirect you back to index unless you send a post to this page.

Try: `www.clubmodel.com.br/ensaios` (*warning: erotic content*)

You will be redirected to www.clubmodel.com.br, once you have clicked on "entrar" you will be able to access the page.

There's anyway of simulating it with curl and get the contents back ?

Yes, I will need to scrap the page contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site requires the cookie to be set. You should specify `CURLOPT_COOKIE` option:

```
$url = "http://www.clubmodel.com.br/ensaios";
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "concordo=entrou");
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
print($content);
```

You can use Firebug to figure that out yourself next time.

Comment: Actually I'm using firebug, I just would like to know where firebug shows that a script is setting a cookie on my machine

Comment: Here is the picture after pressing the button: [image](http://storage3.static.itmages.com/i/12/0724/h_1343075282_1715112_52a81460e4.png). You can see POST request and response with the redirect to the same page. After the redirect browser sends GET request of course. Next, expand first request details: [image](http://storage8.static.itmages.com/i/12/0724/h_1343075429_9867675_df1e669e99.png). You can see the Location header for the redirect and the SetCookie header which is setting new cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the form parameters that you want to use with the `-d` option or one of its variants.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could've warned the site had erotic content. I'm OK with that but some people aren't. Second of all, it's not about POST. The site requires a cookie indicating you agreed to view erotic materials. You need to send that cookie with your every request.

Here, I did the job for you:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "concordo=entrou; domain=www.clubmodel.com.br; path=/");`

Comment: Ok, my bad about the content. So, how did you know that it was about setting up a cookie and not posting something?